# Methods of sharing authentication between SharePoint 2010 and ASP.NET applications?

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, single-sign-on

We're evaluating ways of sharing authentication (to achieve an SSO effect or actual SSO) with SharePoint 2010 and several ASP.NET applications.

The options I've seen so far are to configure SharePoint to use Shibboleth, CAS, InCommon, or something like that; or to host the ASP.NET applications on the same server as SharePoint 2010 and have them use the same Forms authentication ticket.

Would it be possible to host an ASP.NET application within SharePoint so that it can directly check to see if someone is logged in to SharePoint or do something similar?  Are there any other methods that can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by sharing a machine key: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx

1. Try to setup SharePoint for Forms Authetication. Follow steps from 
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136.aspx
2. Share same machine key between SharePoint application and ASP.NET
   application
3. Make sure you have same Authetication cookie path. (You can leave by
   default which is "/")